# Zoom only text box in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, zoom

I'm looking for a way to magnify a text box (and also the name of a file when I'm editing it) when I click on it. So far I found the built-in solution Magnifier, but it zooms the whole screen.

Comment: Have you tried `ctrl+`?

Comment: Hello @DavidPostill thank you for your comment. My goal is to magnify only the local area of the text box, not the entire screen.